# Merging two lists into one providing they are in ascending order function issues in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, list, arraylist

So I am trying to create one list from two providing both are in ascending order (otherwise quit) but are having a hard time coming close to a conclusion. I have tried the following but I have dug myself into an even deeper ditch. Excuse the fact that none of it makes sense, I am extremely new to this language.

```
static List<int> Merge(List<int> myValues, List<int> myValues2)
{
     List<int> result = new List<int>();
     int size = Math.Max(myValues.Count, myValues2.Count);

     for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) 
     {
        if (i < myValues.Count) 
        {
           result.ToArray();
        }
        if (i < myValues2.Count) 
        {
           result.ToArray();
        }
     }return result;

 }
```

in main I have put the following:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        
        List<int> myValues2 = new List<int>{1, 2, 4, 5, 7};
        List<int> myValues = new List<int>{1, 2, 6, 7, 8};
        
        List<int> ret = Merge(myValues, myValues2);
    }
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT

I just changed the numbers in the lists to better represent what I'm trying to achieve. Therefore the outcome would be 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8.

Comment: What's the result you want to get in the end after merging `myValues` and `myValues2`?

Comment: I want to have a new list that contains all the elements of both myValues and myValues2 in ascending order. Sorry if my wording was strange.

Comment: So you're expecting `{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10 }`?

Comment: yes exactly! but both myValues and myValues2 need to be checked first to see if they are in order. otherwise the program should quit.

Answer (score 1):

IMHO, you are too deep into the details already.

What's wrong with your code? [ToArray()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.toarray?view=net-5.0) returns an array, but you never assign it to a variable. That basically makes the whole statement useless, since it does nothing visible. That way, your if statements are empty, resulting in an empty loop.

If I understand the task correctly, you want

```
static List<int> Merge(List<int> myValues, List<int> myValues2)
{
    if (!IsSorted(myValues)) throw new ArgumentException("...");
    if (!IsSorted(myValues2)) throw new ArgumentException("...");

    List<int> result = new List<int>();
    result.AddRange(myValues);
    result.AddRange(myValues2);
    return result;
}
```

It uses [AddRange()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.addrange?view=net-5.0) to add many elements at once.

You can then focus on a more specialized task, checking whether a single list is sorted or not (implement `IsSorted()`).

Note that the overall result may still not be sorted, depending on the input.

```
{1, 10, 100}
{2, 20, 200}
```

are both sorted, but the result would be

```
{1, 10, 100, 2, 20, 200}
```

You can use [Sort()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.generic.list-1.sort?view=net-5.0) to sort the result.

If however, each individual list needs to be sorted and you expect the second list to continue the first list, you need an additional check:

```
if (myValues.Last() > myValues2.First()) throw new ArgumentException("...");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use LINQ and do something like

`myValues.Concat(myValues2).OrderBy(n => n)`

If you want to check if they're sorted beforehand you can do this:

```
var orderedByAsc = input.OrderBy(d => d);
if (myValues.SequenceEqual(orderedByAsc))
{
    Console.WriteLine("Not ordered correctly!");
    return;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems that you want `merged` being sorted; the naive code can be

```
// mechanically concat both lists onto one and sort the result
static List<int> Merge(List<int> x, List<int> y) => (x ?? new List<int>())
  .Concat(y ?? new List<int>())
  .OrderBy(item => item)
  .ToList();
```

when more elaborated (a little bit faster: `O(n)` vs. `O(n * log(n))`) solution can exploit the fact that both list are sorted:

```
static List<int> Merge(List<int> x, List<int> y) {
  if (x == null)
    return y?.ToList(); // ToList() - let's return copy of the argument
  if (y == null)
    return x?.ToList();

  List<int> merged = new List<int>(x.Count + y.Count);

  // loop when at least one list (either x or y) has items 
  for (int ix = 0, iy = 0; ix < x.Count || iy < y.Count; ) 
    if (ix >= x.Count)
      merged.Add(y[iy++]);  // no more items in x
    else if (iy >= y.Count)
      merged.Add(x[ix++]);  // no more items in y
    else if (x[ix] < y[iy])
      merged.Add(x[ix++]);  // current x's item is smaller
    else
      merged.Add(y[iy++]);  // current y's item is smaller

  return merged;
}
```

**Demo:**

```
  List<int> myValues2 = new List<int> { 1, 2, 4, 5, 7 };
  List<int> myValues = new List<int> { 1, 2, 6, 7, 8 };

  List<int> ret = Merge(myValues2, myValues);

  Console.Write(string.Join(", ", ret));
```

**Outcome:**

```
  1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8
```

Comment: Hey Dmitry, thanks for the reply. I just edited my post to better show what I'm trying to achieve. I changed the values in both lists so they are still ascending, but have to be merged to make 1, 1, 2, 2, 4, 5, 6, 7, 7, 8. How would I go about that? cheers!

Comment: @telder08: it seems you have a *typo*: `List<int> ret = Merge(myValues, myValues);` note that you put `myValues` *twice* when you should `List<int> ret = Merge(myValues, myValues2);`

Comment: Thanks! I have changed it